# Matlab subplot in a double loop

Tags: matlab

I have a double loop where I wish to also return a subplot:

```
for j = 1:tileno 
    for k = 1:tileno 

    imsub{j,k} = imgquant(rowdiv*(j-1)+1:rowdiv*j, coldiv*(k-1)+1:coldiv*k);
    subplot(tileno, tileno, ???); hist(imsub{j,k}(:), n_bins);

    end 
end
```

So the code stores some rowdiv*coldiv images in imsub{j,k} and during that loop I wish to plot a histogram of each of these stored images. I tried running a loop over that double loop:

```
for j = 1:tileno 
    for k = 1:tileno 
        for p = 1:tileno^2

    imsub{j,k} = imgquant(rowdiv*(j-1)+1:rowdiv*j, coldiv*(k-1)+1:coldiv*k);
    subplot(tileno, tileno, p); hist(imsub{j,k}(:), n_bins);

        end 
    end
end
```

but this returned the same histogram tileno^2 times, so I think it does a histogram of imsub{1,1} for instance and then subplots this for each p, rather than for each p returning a distinct hist(imsub{j,k}). Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Actually I just noticed I can do subplot(tileno, tileno, tileno*(j-1)+k) and that gives a unique index for each subplot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compute the index manually:

```
for j = 1:tileno 
    for k = 1:tileno 
    plot_index = (j-1)*tileno+k;
    imsub{j,k} = imgquant(rowdiv*(j-1)+1:rowdiv*j, coldiv*(k-1)+1:coldiv*k);
    subplot(tileno, tileno, plot_index hist(imsub{j,k}(:), n_bins);

    end 
end
```

Comment: Spotted that just before your answer! Thanks :)